# "file '.Renviron' cannot be opened for reading" in Docker container running R

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I am currently trying to dockerize an RShiny application I wrote, and I am having issues reading in the .Renviron variable at the beginning of my script. Below is my console output.

```
❯ docker run --rm -p 6969:6969 r-app

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    date, intersect, setdiff, union

── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.0 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.3.3     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
✔ tibble  3.0.6     ✔ dplyr   1.0.4
✔ tidyr   1.1.2     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
✔ readr   1.4.0
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ lubridate::as.difftime() masks base::as.difftime()
✖ readr::col_factor()      masks scales::col_factor()
✖ lubridate::date()        masks base::date()
✖ purrr::discard()         masks scales::discard()
✖ dplyr::filter()          masks stats::filter()
✖ lubridate::intersect()   masks base::intersect()
✖ dplyr::lag()             masks stats::lag()
✖ lubridate::setdiff()     masks base::setdiff()
✖ lubridate::union()       masks base::union()
Warning message:
In readRenviron(".Renviron") :
  file '.Renviron' cannot be opened for reading
Error: Failed to connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Execution halted
```

And below is my Dockerfile. The .Renviron file exists in the same folder as my app.R file, so I'm not sure why it's not able to open it.

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev

# Download and install ShinyServer
RUN wget --no-verbose --no-check-certificate https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb && \
    gdebi shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb

RUN R -e "install.packages('lubridate', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('RMariaDB', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('scales', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('stringr', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tidyverse', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
#COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
#COPY ttp-internal-reporting.Rproj /srv/shiny-server/
#COPY app.R /srv/shiny-server/
#COPY .Renviron /srv/shiny-server/
COPY . /srv/shiny-server/

# select port
EXPOSE 6969

CMD ["Rscript", "srv/shiny-server/app.R"]
```

There is really not a lot of documentation or examples out on the internet for reading in an .Renviron file for a dockerized app, and I do not want to eschew using this file because it contains database credentials for getting our data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I don't remember what exactly was fixed and how (the devops guy on our team figured it out) but I can post the Dockerfile we use now.

Comment: The only solution that we found was to configure the env variables directly to the aws server. It seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get install -y \
            libssl-dev \
            libcurl4-openssl-dev \
            && apt-get clean

RUN R -e 'install.packages("curl")'

RUN R -e 'install.packages("usethis")'

COPY .Renviron /root/.Renviron
```

Using this image, and with this Dockerfile, in the next layers after COPY, when running R commands, it recognizes the variables set in .Renviron

For example, if I had inserted GITHUB_PAT in .Renviron, in the next layers I could install my own private packages from my github

Answer (score 1):

Per [Araê Souza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12226483/ara%c3%aa-souza)'s comment asking for more info, this is the Dockerfile we ended up using.

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev

# Download and install ShinyServer
RUN wget --no-verbose --no-check-certificate https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb && \
    gdebi shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb

RUN R -e "install.packages('lubridate', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('RMariaDB', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('scales', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('stringr', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tidyverse', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

COPY app/ /srv/shiny-server/




# select port
EXPOSE 5000/tcp

CMD R --no-save -e 'library(shiny); runApp(appDir="/srv/shiny-server", port=5000, host="0.0.0.0");'
```